# Change Text Size and Keep Text Vertically Centered

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I change the textSize of a dynamic text field and keep the text resting on the baseline? When I call this function and it affects the size of the text, the text gradually rises upwards within the text field as the text size decreases.

```
function autoFormatSize(myTextField)
{
    if (! textFormat && ! textSize)
    {
        var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var textSize:int = new int();
    }
    textFormat.size = 50;
    textSize = 50;
    for (var i=0; myTextField.textWidth>myTextField.width-10; i++)
    {
        textSize--;
        textFormat.size = textSize;
        myTextField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a visual illustration of what I'm trying to do:
[image: ProcessIllustration]

Comment: Do you need the baseline to be at the very same position? Or would it be satisfactory to vertically align the text in the textfield to the bottom?

Comment: Either would be fine, my main goal is to keep the text from floating upwards as it's size decreases @Fygo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use textHeight to get the height of the text.  Here is how you'd position a textfield over an mc of a line:

```
var tfMain: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tfMain.size = 100;
tMain.setTextFormat(tfMain);
trace(tMain.textHeight);            
tMain.y = Math.ceil(mcUnderline.y - tMain.textHeight);
```

Use ceil to make sure it's on the x.

Comment: This definitely did not work for me... it was cutting off text and moving the text field. thanks for helping though

Comment: textHeight is the solution.  You want to center the text and position it over the text below (code I gave you).  You also need to move both text fields up or down (like in example you gave).  You need that code too?

Comment: myText.y += Math.round((myText.height - myText.textHeight) / 2); There it is you were right

Comment: Ok, good.  Yeah, you're going to use textHeight all the time to make text look good.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Sprite and added it to stage, then align your TexField based on the Sprite. As coded below

```
with(bg.graphics) {
        clear();
        beginFill(0xeeeeee, 1);
        lineStyle(1, 0x999999);
        drawRect(0, 0, 200, 30);
        endFill();
    }
    txt.x = bg.x + bg.width/2 - txt.width/2;
    txt.y = bg.y + bg.height/2 - txt.height/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comment, have you thought about using autoSize instead? Something like:

```
var tf:TextField = yourTextField; //on timeline

tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.size = 14;
var oldY:Number = tf.y + tf.height;

tf.setTextFormat(textFormat);
tf.y = oldY - tf.height;
```

Comment: I'll try this code out the first chance I get. Thanks for the assistance @Fygo

Comment: @DrakeSwartzy You're welcome but it doesn't seem to work in what way exactly?

Comment: I don't want to change the text field's dimensions, rather I want the text to move and re-size to fit within it.

Comment: @DrakeSwartzy Do you need to keep it as text? (=does it need to be selectable/editable?)

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your text to your text field, you have to consider a [2px gutter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html) for each side of the text, so your function can be like this :

```
function autoFormatSize(myTextField)
{
    var gutter:int = 2 * 2;  // 4px

    var textSize:int = 50;
    var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        textFormat.size = textSize;

    for (var i:int = 0; myTextField.textWidth > myTextField.width - gutter; i++)
    {
        textSize --;
        textFormat.size = textSize;
        myTextField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
    }

    myTextField.height = myTextField.textHeight + gutter;

}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: unfortunately I don't want the text field to be altered in dimensions. Thank you for your help though